# I want to make enemies look at player when they spawn in

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Unity will not let me set the "Transform target" as the player until the enemy exists in the game. What do I change to make it automatically target the player without specifying the target through unity? Here's my code.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PawnRotate : MonoBehaviour
{
    //public Transform target;
    public Transform target;
    public float speed = 3f;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.position) > 1f)
        {
            RotateTowards(target.position);
            target = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Player>().transform;
        }
    }


    private void RotateTowards(Vector2 target)
    {
        var offset = 90f;
        Vector2 direction = target - (Vector2)transform.position;
        direction.Normalize();
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.forward * (angle + offset));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Does this answer your question? [Accessing object's position from another script in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10019653/1092820)

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html or https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html ..  or assign it in the script that spawns the enemy instances

Comment: Actually you just need to use `Quaternion.LookRotation` with the relative location position of the object you are trying to face https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html

Comment: @OmarAbdelBari Despite using this code, I am still confronted with the same problem. The preset for the objects that spawn in needs me to clarify the transform target through unity. But, there are no options to select when I try.

Comment: If the game object is not already in the scene (via the editor) then it needs to be set at runtime.

Comment: @OmarAbdelBari How would I go about doing that?

Comment: So my guess is these enemies will be a prefab object which would prevent you from setting the player as the target in the editor. What you would need in the script that spawns (instantiates) the enemy object is to take a reference of the instantiation `var enemy = Instantiate(...);` Assuming `PawnRotate` is the mono script for the enemy you would then `var pawnRotateComponent = enemy.GetComponent<PawnRotate>();` In the spawn script it store the Transform of the player as a public variable which you should be able to set in the editor. Pass the player's transform to `pawnRotateComponent`

Comment: Make sure the prefab is set to inactive. That way start is only run after you set it active. You activate the object after it's been instantiated and you set all the properties that need to be set. This is good for both performance and will make it work in this situation. This assumes that `PawnRotate` is a script attached to the prefab object at the root level.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of ways of doing this.
Basically, you need to find the player's GameObject (or Transform) by code.

**By Tag**
If your player has a Tag, you can use `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag` (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html) to find it.

```
private void Start()
{
    target = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player").transform; // "Player" should be your player tag
}
```

**By Script**
If your player has a unique script, you can use `GameObject.FindObjectOfType` (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html) to find it.

```
private void Start()
{
    target = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Player>().transform; // "Player" should be your player MonoBehaviour script
}
```

There are other ways of doing this too.
Ex: using Singletons, some type of GameController that has a reference to the player, etc.

*PS: Both ways expects that the Player object is already in the scene*

Comment: The player object is in the scene, but it still does not work. I did what you said but it is still looking for a "Transform" and not a game object, "player".

Comment: Which method did you choose? Can you post your new code?

Comment: I tried both. Code is updated.

Comment: Are you saying that you have an issue with it requesting a transform instead of a gameobject? The hierarchy in Unity is based on transforms, there should be no problem. Also you can access the gameobject of the transform via `gameobject` (might be `gameObject`) property.

Comment: @JasonTrager You are trying to find the target after using. It should be the first thing in the start method. And you have a Player script attached to the Player game object, right?

Comment: @JasonTrager you can also use `GameObject.Find("Player").transform` (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html) as suggested by derHugo.